# git cli language default to first non english value

Tags: kde, git, locale

I have my computer language set to `en_GB` with `fr_FR` as backup only for spellcheck and money/measurement formatting purposes.

CLI apps work fine like that except git, who insist on using the first non english value provided in `$LANGUAGE`.

```bash
LANGUAGE=en_GB:fr git          # git's in french
LANGUAGE=fr:en_GB git          # also french
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_US:en:fr git # still french
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_US:fr:de git # still french
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en_US:de:fr git # german this time
```

I tried many other value (even `en_EN` just to see), and it seems git CLI always takes the first non english locale.

Why is that? And is there a way to correctly setup my computer locales without having to rely on an alias like `git='LANGUAGE=en git`?

Some more info on my setup:

```bash
% echo $LANG
en_GB.UTF-8

% echo $LANGUAGE
en_GB:fr

% locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I did not edit anything by hand or in my `.bashrc`, all values were set by KDE plasma from the language settings in the GUI.

Comment: See [How Does One Change Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633564/how-does-one-change-the-language-of-the-command-line-interface-of-git) which recommends what you've already discovered, i.e. use of an alias.

Comment: @eyoung100 yeah that's what i though even tho i would want rather not to, and that still doesn't explain why the cli is doing that :/

Comment: It's a limitation of the client, and also the only approach I found so far.

Comment: I think this is a glibc thing, because invoking `ls --help` produces the same behaviour.  My guess is that there's no actual `en` translation, which is the problem; it picks the first value for which there _is_ a translation, but the default is English and nobody has written an English-English translation, so `fr` is “better“.